# Twilio Voice (Twiml) - Dialogflow ES integration: Twilio responsds before Dialogflow webhook call returns data

Tags: dialogflow-es, twilio-api, voice, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, twilio-twiml

We are implementing twilio media stream to connect google dialogflow  agent.
We have implemented twiml response in webhook.

It seems twilio is ignoring the webhook response and only returns default response added in dialogflow intent.
Twillio reads out default response even before dialogflow calls webhook.
If I remove the default response in Dialogflow Intent, then twilio is not giving any response.

I want Twilio to respond based on what Dialogflow Webhook call returns.

Any gudidance will be very helpful.